# ionicGestures not working in Mobile Device

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm trying to have swipe gesture in my app using ionic framework. The code is working in my browser well but when I install/run it in mobile device no gestures are working.

Here is my code

```
app.directive('detectGestures', function ($ionicGesture) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',

        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
            var gestureType = attrs.gestureType;
            $ionicGesture.on('swipeup', scope.reportEvent, elem);
            $ionicGesture.on('swipedown', scope.reportEvent, elem);
            $ionicGesture.on('swiperight', scope.reportEvent, elem);
            $ionicGesture.on('swipeleft', scope.reportEvent, elem);
        }
    };
});
```

Controller.js

```
$scope.reportEvent = function (event) {
    alert("1");
    console.log('Reporting : ' + event.type);
    event.preventDefault();

    login();
};
```

Comment: Have you got any error messages when you run it from the device?

Comment: NO... even request does't get hit..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do swipe event in my ion-content thus:

```
<ion-content on-swipe-left="swipe();">
```

In controller:

```
$scope.swipe = function () {
        $state.go("main.agenda.allEvents");
    }
```

It has worked.